# Get dynamic Class Names

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, getelementsbyclassname

For testing I have the alert, so the problem seem to be before the alert.

it throws errors at:

```
var firstPrevClass= "categClass"+PrevClass;

var newCategory = document.getElementsByClassName(firstPrevClass);
```

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Basically in function `addCategory` I want to create dynamically new divs with different class names (which is creating dynamically).
After that I want to append the new category after the last category.
In function  `addField`  I want to put a new field at the category which selected from the selection box.

In function `getClass` I get the selected className so I can create a new field in the selected div.

How to do it?

```js
/*add new category to SelextBox*/

function addCategory() {
    var categoryValue = document.getElementById("newCateg").value;
    var y = document.getElementById('selectCategory');
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    var hid = document.getElementById("nextValue").value;
    var newClass = "categClass" + hid;
    option.setAttribute("class", newClass);
    option.value = categoryValue;
    option.text = categoryValue;
    y.add(option);
    var PrevClass = hid-1 ;/*i do this to get the first previous class*/
    var firstPrevClass= "categClass"+PrevClass;
alert(newClass);
    var newCategory = document.getElementsByClassName(firstPrevClass);
   
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class',newClass );

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.setAttribute('class', 'titles');

    var input_checkC = document.createElement('input');
    input_checkC.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    input_checkC.setAttribute('class', 'check');


    var textNodeCateg = document.createTextNode(categoryValue);

    div.appendChild(a);
    div.appendChild(input_checkC);
    div.appendChild(textNodeCateg);
    
    
    var last = newCategory.length;
    newCategory[last].appendChild(div);


    document.getElementById("nextValue").value++;

    alert(newClass);
}

    function getClass(sel) {
       var x =sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].className;
       document.getElementById("submitSelection").value=x;
    }

function addField() {
   var val = document.getElementById("submitSelection").value;
    var existedCategory = document.getElementsByClassName(val);
    
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById("newField").value;

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    var input_check = document.createElement('input');
    input_check.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
    input_check.setAttribute('class', 'check');

    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');

    var br = document.createElement('br');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(fieldValue);

    div.appendChild(input_check);
    div.appendChild(textnode);
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(br);

   
    existedCategory.appendChild(div);

}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Προσθέστε το όνομα της νέας κατηγορίας</li>
    <p>Ονομα Kατηγορίας:
        <label>
            <input type="text" id="newCateg" />
        </label>
        <input type="button" id="addCateg" value="Προσθήκη" onclick=" addCategory()" />
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <li>Επιλέξετε κατω απο ποια κατηγορία θα ανήκει το νεο πεδίο και εισάγεται το όνομα του νέου πεδίου.</li>
    <p>Κατηγορία:</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="4" id="nextValue" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="submitSelection" />
    <select id="selectCategory" onchange="getClass(this)">
        <option>Επιλογή ...</option>
        <option class="categClass1">Εξοδα Κατοικίας</option>
        <option class="categClass2">Εξοδα Εκπαίδευσης</option>
        <option class="categClass3">Εξοδα Ψηχαγωγίας</option>
    </select>
    <p>Ονομα πεδίου:
        <label>
            <input type="text" id="newField" />
            <input type="button" value="Προσθήκη" onclick="addField()" />
            <br />
        </label>
    </p>
    <div class="class_1">
        <p class="titles">
            <input type="checkbox" class="catChk1 check" onchange="checkAll(subCheck1,subChks)" />Εξοδα Kατοικιας</p>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Ενοίκιο
            <input type="text" />
            </br>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Θέρμανση
            <input type="text" />
            </br>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input type="checkbox" class="subCheck1 check" />Διάφορα Yλικά
            <input type="text" />
            </br>
        </div>
        <div class="class_2">
            <p class="titles">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" onchange="checkAll(this)" />Εξοδα Εκπαίδευσης παιδιού</p>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Φροντιστήρια
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Βιβλία
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="checkbox" class="check" />Σχολική Υλη
                <input type="text" />
                </br>
            </div>
            <div class="class_3">
                <p class="titles">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check chk" onchange="checkAll(this)" />Για Ψυχαγωγία</p>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
                    <label>Θέατρο</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    </br>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
                    <label>Ψάρεμα</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    </br>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check" />
                    <label>Γήπεδο</label>
                    <input type="text" />
                    </br>
                </div>
```

Comment: *"For testing i have the alert ,so the problem seem to be before the alert."* - What problem? You've kind of explained what you want the code to do, but not what happens when you run it. Are any errors displayed in your browser's dev console?

Comment: Right! i edited it :)

Comment: You could tell us the text of the errors. But in the meantime you've got a typo: `getElementsyClassName` is missing the `B` in `By`: should be `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: i edited it  
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
But i do not know how to solve this.It seems complicated

Comment: That's the error I'd have expected when you were still missing the `B`.

Comment: now there in not error but the code does not work properlyr

Comment: `hid` is treated as a number but it's value is never converted or coerced into a number when it was retrieved from `#nextValue`, it's still a string. So the fastest way to fix to coerce `hid` into a number by `+hid`